# Getting error: code = Unknown desc = docker.io/library/java:8: not found

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have been using Docker with an image for the last few months, and then. I stared getting the following error

```
[+] Building 3.3s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental                                                                                                             1.9s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:600e5c62eedff338b3f7a0850beb7c05866e0ef27b2d2e8c02aa468e78496ff5                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.2-jdk-8                                                                                                              0.9s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8                                                                                                                   1.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = docker.io/library/java:8: not found
```

I ran the following command on the container that the image sits in

```
docker exec container_name java -version
```

I got back

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I am not an expert on docker, and I have no idea how I can list whatis in the directory docker.io/library/

Dockerfile calls java 8.

All I know was that it was working, and now its stopped working

Thankyou for any help, and/or pointers.

Comment: The name of the file should be `Dockerfile` and it is case sensitive. Are you using vscode to send the build command? Maybe it's lowercasing the file name. Refer
https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/415

Comment: It is called Dockerfile. That was just a mistake on my part when writing my comment. As I pointed out it was working, and then just stopped working. 
Do you know how I can ls on the directory docker.io/library

Answer (score 0):

in the `Dockerfile`

```bash
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

This one works for me